# Convert dynamic memory allocation to static

Tags: c++, pointers

I'd like to change this code from dynamic allocation to static. Node is a struct containing other nodes. The point of the function reverse is to change the order of head node which is filled with a node containing another node containing another node etc... This works fine using dynamic allocation, but could not figure it out transforming this into static allocation.

```
struct Node {
    Node *succ;
    int val;
    Node (int pval) : val{ pval }, succ {} {
    }
};
void reverse() {
   Node *new_head = {};
   while(head) {
     auto p = new Node{*head};
     p->succ = new_head;
     new_head = p;
     p = head;
     head = head->succ;
     delete p;
   }
   head = new_head;
}
```

Comment: Linked lists require dynamic memory allocation

Comment: `reverse()` can be implemented by adjusting links between existing nodes, without allocating any new memory. Instead, you allocate a set of new nodes which are copies of the existing ones, and deleting the originals. This is quite unnecessary.

Comment: This is impossible according to the fundamental laws of physics of this universe. Something like this would result in a `Node` that logically contains another `Node`, that logically contains another `Node`, and so on, infinitely. This results in an infinite object. Unless your computer has an infinite amount of RAM, this will not be possible, sadly. Fortunately, trying to compile this will not result in your computer imploding, because your C++ compiler will flatly refuse such a thing, mumbling something about an "incomplete type", thusly preventing a black hole from forming.

Comment: I don't see why you can't have a static array of Nodes to use as a "memory pool" of sorts.. and your 'new' and 'delete' and be instead functions that grab and return from this pool of Nodes.

Comment: Exercise: Reverse the list using bounded memory without any dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how you can do it without dynamical allocation:

```
void inverser() {
        Noeud *end{ queue };
        for (; end != tete;) {
            Noeud *old_tete{ tete };
            for (; old_tete->succ != end; old_tete = old_tete->succ);
            end->succ = old_tete;
            old_tete->succ = nullptr;
            end = old_tete;
        }
        tete = queue;
    }
```

hope it helps you